# Send notification at each new permission - Azure

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

I am trying to create new alert  to send notification at new permission created but i didn't get what i want .

This what i am talking about: 
[image]

Comment: Have you checked this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-roles-permissions-security and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-activity-logs

Comment: yes but i didn't find what i want

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, I think you are asking for an alert to be generated when an role assignment is made in your subscription. If yes,

You may use Azure Monitor for your use case.

In Azure Monitor blade, you need to create an alert as follows

a. Specify the target resource (in your case, your subscription),

b. Define an alert criteria (when you configure signal, choose administrative activity log > create role assignments / delete role assignments)

c. Create an action group. You can specify an email address to which the alerts will be sent

Once setup, every time a new role is assigned, an email alert will be sent to the email id specified in the Action Group

You may explore Event Grids also for your scenario